# How to get correct frame and and only initialize once in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm creating a couple of UIButtons programmatically in a UITableViewCell, and setting its frame in `layoutSubviews`. I am also setting the selected state here as well.

However, it seems this is not the best place to either create, nor initialize the state of the buttons because `layoutSubviews` is called multiple times. Where can I put the following code such that the frame will be correct, but it will only be initialized once?

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height)];
button.selected = YES
```

One idea I have is to initialize all the one-time setup in `awakeFromNib`, then do the actual frame setting in `layoutSubviews`. Is that a good approach?

Comment: The best approach will be to create prototype UITableViewCell in storyboard and put all your UIButtons there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NIB file for your custom `UITableViewCell` class then `awakeFromNib` is the method where you should initialize your UIElements, class properties and other instance variables of your `UITableViewCell` class.

Else if you are using a custom `UITableViewCell` class **without** a NIB then you should initialize everything in

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize your frames here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now if you want to update your cell with different button states or data, then you just call a method in your cell from the

```
- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

and change whatever you want to for that particular cell.

Ex:

```
- tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndecPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    [cell someMethod];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: awakeFromNib is where I want to initialize elements, but it doesn't seem to be where I want to be laying things out, because frame is wrong at this point. So am I correct in initializing there then setting frames in layoutSubviews?

Comment: Yes you are right! You should initialize your buttons in awakeFromNib: method and set the frames in layoutSubviews. But you should override this method (layoutSubviews) only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend placing it in the

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

and using Autolayout for button placement. I'll show you how using Masonry for Autolayout to save on lines.

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton new];
        button.selected = YES;
        // Add button to self
        [self addSubview:button];

        [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.mas_top);
            make.left.equalTo(self.mas_left);
            make.width.mas_equalTo(self.view.frame.size.width/2);
            make.height.equalTo(self.mas_height);
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: So the frame is accurate in this method?

Comment: What do you mean by 'frame is accurate'?

Comment: As in, if you need to call self.view.frame or the like, these dimensions will be accurate. They are not finalized and are inaccurate if you call that in awakeFromNib.